# How to iterate a Map in Aura

Tags: lightning-aura-components, map, iteration

I have a aura map attribute defined in my component file as below

`<aura:attribute name="FilesNameMap" type="Map">`

But i am not able to understand how to iterate this in the component file as we know that  the  < aura:iteration > will work on List but not for Map.

Below is the code which i tried to iterate the Map but couldn't succeed.

```
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.FilesNameMap}" indexVar="key" var="item">
                    //- logic                   
 </ aura:iteration>
```

Please let me know how can i iterate the Map in Aura component to fetch key and value pairs.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you have to add quite a lot of boiler-plate if this [How to iterate map in Salesfore Lightning?](http://www.infallibletechie.com/2016/05/how-to-iterate-map-in-salesfore.html) example is typical. Looks like it would be worth doing more work in the Apex controller to avoid the situation, particularly as AFAIK there is no build-in way to test the JavaScript in Lightning.

Answer (score 7):

Pretty much all browsers support the JavaScript method `Object.keys()` which takes in an object and returns an array of just its keys. So you could have a second attribute of type `String[]` and set it in the controller equal to `Object.keys(theMapYouWantToIterate)`. A bit more troublesome though is the fact that you can't actually look up that index of the map in Aura binding notation (e.g `{!v.myMap[key]}` doesn't work).

So if you need to iterate and use both the name and values, you might alternatively want to pass it to the controller as a list of objects (i.e. `Map[]`) where each object has a `name` and a `value`. If you have no choice but to start with a map in the controller, you can transform it to a list of objects something like this: `var listOfObjects = Object.keys(myMap).map(function(key){return {name: key, value: myMap[key]} })`.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the way I solved this is by creating a list of JS objects, which had the value of my key as one attribute, and then had a list representing the items that were in that key.

This way, you can use aura:interation for your map by first doing an aura:interation on the outside object (the key), and then doing a nested aura:iteration on the list (the keys contents).

---

To explain my use case, I needed to get a list of sObjects back from SF, but I needed them grouped based on the value of a field.  Normally you could create an `Map<String, List<sObject>>` for something like that, but aura:iteration doesn't work with maps.

So what I did instead was have the apex return just a list....

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<myCustomObj__c> apex_myCustomObjs(String accountId) {
    List<myCustomObj__c> objList = new List<myCustomObj__c>();
    for(myCustomObj__c myObj: [SELECT Id, someField__c, someOtherField__c FROM myCustomObj__c WHERE Account__c = :accountId]) {
        objList.add(myObj);
    }
    return objList;
}
```

And in my component controller, I do the to take this list and compile it into something like a map...

```
// Go and call my apex class...
var myAction = component.get('c.apex_myCustomObjs');
myAction.setParams({
    "accountId": someVariableWhereYouHaveAnId
});
// Handle returned results...
myAction.setCallback(this, function(response) {
    var state = response.getState();
    if(component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
        var result = response.getReturnValue();

        // Place to store our list of objects
        // This will be an array of JS objects that look like:
        // { "key": "some value", "list": [{ ... }] }
        // ...where "list" is your list of items in that key
        var myObjectMap = [];

        // Loop through results; remember, this is a list of sObjects
        for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
            // Get the record
            var myRecord = result[i];
            // Pull out the field that's going to be my key
            var myKey = myRecord.someField__c

            // Keep track of whether our key already exists in myObjectMap
            var found = false;
            // Loop through our map and see if an entry for our key exists
            for(var x=0; x<myObjectMap.length; x++) {
                // Look to see if our object has a "key" value
                // and whether that key is equal to the key we want
                // to use to group everything
                if("key" in myObjectMap[x] && myObjectMap[x]["key"] == myKey) {
                    myObjectMap[x]["list"].push(myRecord);
                    // We found our key and pushed the record into its
                    // list, no need to continue
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Need to make sure this record found a home; if it didn't
            // then we need to initialize it in our "map"
            if(!found) {
                var temp = { "key": myKey, "list": [myRecord] };
                myObjectMap.push(temp);
            }
        }

        component.set('v.listOfMyCustomObject', myObjectMap);

        /*
        At the end of all this, myObjectMap should look something like...
        [
            {
                "key": "value 1"
                , "list": [
                    {
                        ...json representation of myCustomObj__c...
                    }
                    , {
                        ....another record...
                    }
                ]
            }
            , {
                "key": "value 2"
                , "list": [
                    {
                        ...another record...
                    }
                ]
            }
        ];

        */
    } else {
        // error handling
    }
});
```

Now that you've got that, you'll iterate twice in your component over these two lists, one on the external list and the other inside...

```
<aura:attribute name="listOfMyCustomObject" type="object[]" default="[]" />

<aura:iteration items="{!v.listOfMyCustomObject}" var="outside">
    <h1>{!outside.key}</h1>
    <ul>
    <aura:iteration items="{!outside.list}" var="inside">
        <li>{!inside.someField__c} - {!inside.someOtherField__c}</li>
    </aura:iteration>
    </ul>
</aura:iteration>
```

Now, that was my use case, which might not fit yours.

The main thing is that aura:iteration only uses Lists/Arrays, so if you can figure out what you need to do to turn your map into a list of lists, then the above should hopefully point you towards a solution.